# Database Design: Complex Voting System

Tags: database, database-design, mysql

I have three tables `Feed`, `Vote` and `Event`.

```
Feed
+id
+content
+voteCount  --> hold the number of votes on this feed

Vote
+id
+feedId --> FK to id in Feed
+eventId --> FK to id in Event

Event
+id
+name
+voteCount --> hold the number of votes on this event
```

Both `event` and `feed` can be up-voted by user. The `Vote` table keep track of who has been voting on what since, each only allow to vote once on an `event` or `feed`. So here is my problem: when I create an `event Y`, I will aslo create a `feed` say `X created event Y` which will appear on the user `X` profile. If someone vote on **either** the feed **or** event Y, the vote of **both** the `event Y` and the vote of the `feed` that said `X created event Y` should **both** be 1.

**a. What is the best way to achieve the above**?

**b. Also if `X` already vote on the `feed` that said `X created event Y`, then he cant vote on `event Y` anymore and vice versa (since each user can only vote once on an event, and in this case the `feed` and the `event` really is the same thing)**

Comment: Based on your question, I think you need a foreign key relationship between feed and event.

Answer (score 1):

This data-model treats events and feeds separately, but can record the parent `Candidate`. The special (?) case of combined votes can be handled in the application layer, by allowing  votes only on the root Candidate `WHERE ParentId is NULL`.

[image]